# Getting error in hapi server

Tags: javascript, node.js, hapi.js

I am building a simple log app and have tried to implement modularity to make the code more readable. However I am running into some trouble when I start my app. I have two files, `index.js` which is where I have my server configuration and have `routes.js` where I have my routing logic.
The way I have written my routes is in accordance to the api documentation found in [the hapi api](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#route-options).

I am hoping someone could help me understand why I am getting the following error:

```
/Users/mario/projects/loGym/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:425
    throw new Error(msgs.join(' ') || 'Unknown error');
          ^
Error: Missing or undefined handler: /
    at Object.exports.assert (/Users/mario/projects/loGym/node_modules/hapi/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js:425:11)
    at new module.exports.internals.Route (/Users/mario/projects/loGym/node_modules/hapi/lib/route.js:36:10)
    at /Users/mario/projects/loGym/node_modules/hapi/lib/router.js:110:25
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at /Users/mario/projects/loGym/node_modules/hapi/lib/router.js:107:17
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at internals.Router.add (/Users/mario/projects/loGym/node_modules/hapi/lib/router.js:104:13)
    at internals.Server._route (/Users/mario/projects/loGym/node_modules/hapi/lib/server.js:471:18)
    at internals.Server.route (/Users/mario/projects/loGym/node_modules/hapi/lib/server.js:465:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/mario/projects/loGym/index.js:10:8)
```

Am I not exporting the module correctly?

Here is my code for `routes.js`:

```
var path = require('path');
var _ = require('underscore');
var couchbase = require('couchbase');

//Connect to database.

var db = db || new couchbase.Connection({host: 'localhost:8091', bucket: 'default'}, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Connection Error', err);
    } else {
      console.log('Connected!');
  }
 });
console.log(db);


module.exports = [
    {method: 'GET', path: '/static/{param*}', config: { handler: { directory: { path: 'static'}}}},
    {method: 'GET', path:'/', config: landingPage},
    {method: 'GET', path:'/workouts', config: getWorkouts},
    {method: 'GET', path:'/workouts/musclegroup', config: getMusclegroup},
    {method: 'POST', path:'/addworkout', config: addWorkout}
];



var landingPage = {
    handler: function(req, reply) {
        reply.file('index.html');
    }
};

var getWorkouts = {
    handler: function (req, reply) {
        // set options for databse query
        var q ={
          descending: true,
          stale: false
        };

        // show multiple exercises - db.view(designDocument, viewName, options)
        db.view('workout', 'exercise', q).query(function(err, values){
            // use pluck method from underscore to retrieve data
            var keys = _.pluck(values, 'id');
            console.log("Keys: " + keys);

            //fetch multiple documents based on the 'keys' object
            db.getMulti(keys, null, function(err, results){
                console.log('Results: ' + results);

                var workouts = [];
                for (var prop in results) {
                  workouts.push(results[prop].value);
                }
                reply(workouts);
            });
        });
    }
};


var getMusclegroup = {
  handler: function (req, reply) {
        var q = {
          descending: true,
          stale: false
        };

        db.view('workout', 'exercise', q).query(function(err, values){

            var keys = _.pluck(values, 'id');

            db.getMulti(keys, null, function(err, results){

                var muscleGroups = [];
                for (var prop in results) {
                    console.log(typeof results);
                    console.log(results[prop].value.workout);
                    muscleGroups.push(results[prop].value.workout);
                }
                reply(muscleGroups[0]);
            });
        });
    }
};


var addWorkout = {
    handler: function(req, reply){

      var d = new Date();
      var cd = d.getDate() + "-" + (d.getMonth()+1) + "-" + d.getFullYear();

      // sets schema for workout
      var payload = {
          "personId": "personId", //to later be replaced with actual username
          "date": cd,
          "workout": [
              {
                "exercise": req.query.exercise,
                "musclegoup": req.query.musclegroup,
                "sets": [
                  {
                    "reps": req.query.reps,
                    "kg": req.query.kg
                  }
                ]
              }
          ]
      };

      // defines unique key for data
      var key = payload.personId + payload.date;
      console.log(key);

      // adds payload to database
      db.add(key, payload, function(error, results){
          if (error) {
              console.log(error);
              reply(error + "\n");
          }
          console.log(results);
          reply(payload);
      });
    }
};
```

And this is my code for `index.js`:

```
var Hapi = require('hapi');
var path = require('path');
var Joi = require('joi');
var rs = require('./lib/modules/routes.js');


var config= { };
var server = Hapi.createServer(process.env.PORT || 8080, config);

server.route(rs);

server.start(function(){
  console.log("Server started: " + server.info.uri);
});

module.exports = server;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to use the `landingPage`, `getWorkouts`, `getMusclegroup`, and `addWorkout` variables before they are defined. So to solve this issue, simply change the order, first define those variables and then create the routes:

```
var landingPage = {
    ...
};

var getWorkouts = {
    ...
};

var getMusclegroup = {
    ...
};

var addWorkout = {
    ...
};

module.exports = [
    {method: 'GET', path: '/static/{param*}', config: { handler: { directory: { path: 'static'}}}},
    {method: 'GET', path:'/', config: landingPage},
    {method: 'GET', path:'/workouts', config: getWorkouts},
    {method: 'GET', path:'/workouts/musclegroup', config: getMusclegroup},
    {method: 'POST', path:'/addworkout', config: addWorkout}
];
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't realise that! Such a beginner mistake! Many thanks!